# Using a return value from a method in another method

Tags: java, methods, return

I'm trying to use the return value "average" in calcAverage method into the determineGrade method to get out a char value (A B C D F).

However, it repeats the loop when I code this way. Is there a way to just get the return value from the calcAverage and not have to execute the loop again and ask the same test scores?

```
package Chapter5;

import java.util.Scanner; 
public class TestAverageAndGradewithLoop {

public static void main(String[] args) {    

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("How many tests?: "); 
    int test = input.nextInt();         

    System.out.print("Average test score is: " + calcAvergage(test)  );

    int mark = calcAvergage(test);

    System.out.print("Letter grade is: " + determineGrade(mark) );      
}

public static int calcAvergage(int test){

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int total = 0;      
    int x;

    for (x = 1; x <= test; x++)
    {
        System.out.print("What is the score for test " + x + " : ");
        int scores = input.nextInt(); 

        total = total + scores; 
    }

    int average = total/(x-1); //have to do -1 because the final increment value of x is stored as x+1

    return average;
}

public static char determineGrade(int average)
{       
    char mark = 0;

    if (average >= 90 && average <= 100)    
    {       
         mark = 'A'; 
    }           
    else if (average >= 80 && average <= 89)
    {       
         mark = 'B'; 
    }       
    else if (average >= 70 && average <= 79)
    {       
         mark = 'C'; 
    }       
    else if (average >= 60 && average <= 69)
    {       
         mark = 'D'; 
    }   
    else if (average <= 60)
    {       
        mark = 'F'; 
    }       

    return mark;    
}
```

}

Comment: Loads of superfluous blank lines do not make your code easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
System.out.print("Average test score is: " + calcAvergage(test)  );

int mark = calcAvergage(test);
```

Do this

```
int mark = calcAvergage(test);    
System.out.print("Average test score is: " + mark  );
```

There is no need to call the function twice when you are playing with the return value. Assign it to a variable and then use it.

Comment: thank you for your answer (and all those who posted). so with my code, I had no problem printing the score with 

System.out.print("Average test score is: " + calcAvergage(test)  );

and I did indeed store that value into the variable mark to use to print the letter grade. 

I'm confused in the sequence in which this happened. Why does the variable mark have to be used in printing the average score first to be displayed in the printing of letter grade?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
int mark = calcAvergage(test);
System.out.print("Average test score is: " + mark);
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you do not want to input a number then press enter then enter another number then press enter and so on...

If you say you have 3 test cases in console just type 3 space separated numbers like 10 12 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing and your code has logical errors, im sorry. You have if statements using the same logic.(example below) I would say learn up more on programming logic and you will answer your own question

```
else if (average >= 60 && average <= 69)
{

     mark = 'D'; 
}


else if (average <= 60)
{

    mark = 'F'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx to Avinash Raj for the pointer. I understand now.

the result of the calcAverage is stored in the variable mark, then I can use the int value from the result to both display what the score is as well as display and execute the determineGrade method.